# how to pipe output with double quotes

Tags: windows, command-line, mplayer, cmd.exe

i want to pipe a URL to mplayer.
but can't see how to encapsulate 1st output with double quotes (otherwise mplayer errors out)

this is wrong

```
youtube-dl.exe -g http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNPVt3cMkT0 | mplayer
```

relevant?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952295/set-output-of-a-command-as-a-variable-with-pipes

another option is to write/read from temp file.

Comment: What error do you get? The quotes will not affect `mplayer`, they will affect `youtube-dl.exe`. What exactly is the output of `youtube-dl.exe -g`? Is that a stream?

Comment: @terdon you are right, the error is coming from youtube-dl
seems its sees  mplayer as an argument.

Comment: @terdon `youtube-dl -g $watch_URI` outputs a very, _very_ long URI with lots of parameters. It looks like a “direct” video link.

Comment: @yoshco Firstly, you want quotes around the YouTube URI, in order to escape the `?`. Secondly, does `mplayer` actually take links to videos on `stdin` like that?

Comment: youtube-dl works either with or without quotes for simple urls
it doesn't change the situation.

Comment: @BlacklightShining, yes mplayer takes url as input and plays them.
what youtub-dl is doing in --get-url mode is parsing the yt link into a valid mp4/webm/flv stream mplayer can work with. suppliyng that url to mplayer semi manualy works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to pipe the result into mplayer, instead you want to supply the result as an argument, like so:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('youtube-dl.exe -g "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNPVt3cMkT0"') do @mplayer "%%A"
```

If used within a batch file, then double up all percents, so `%A` becomes `%%A`.

Comment: this worked. just had to add double quotes around the youtube link itself.
thanks

Comment: @yoshco - I added the quotes to the answer, thanks :)

Comment: worked for me too... for piping the same output to ffplay (from command-line):  do @ffplay -i "%A"  [%%A didn't work].

Answer (score 0):

I googled for an `mplayer` manual page; from what I can tell, it takes URIs as arguments. As I mentioned in the comments, you need to quote the YouTube URI. You'll also need to quote the command substitution, so the shell doesn't try to expand *that* into filenames, too. You want something like this:

```
mplayer "$(youtube-dl --get-url 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNPVt3cMkT0')"
```

(`--get-url` is equivalent to `-g`; I changed it for clarity for those not familiar with `youtube-dl`.)

Comment: your answer refers to unix systems. im on windows

Comment: Single quotes, double quotes, and `$()`-style command substitution are all specified in POSIX and should work the same in any shell.

Comment: im gettign following erro msg  
No stream found to handle url $(youtube-dl --get-url 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNPVt3cMkT0')

Comment: Your shell must not be POSIX-compliant. \*shrug\* You could always install `bash` or something.